# Not reading each line of text file

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that reads a line from a text document and prints the verbal equation into a mathematical one, but for some reason it is only reading the second and last lines of the TXT file.

Text example

```
subtraction,3,57
multiplication,90,46
division,26,7
division,26,0
```

Code

```
int main()
{
  char name[21], namecopy[21];
  char *nc, com = 100;
  int num1, num2, p, i;
  FILE *file;

  file = fopen("C:\\hw10.txt", "r");
  strcpy(namecopy, name);

  while (fgets (namecopy,21,file)!=NULL)
  {
    fscanf(file, "%[^,]%*c %i%*c %i%*c", &name, &num1, &num2);
    printf("%s %i %i\n", name, num1, num2);     

    if( strcmp( name, "subtraction" ) == 0 )
    {
      p = num1-num2;
      printf("%d - %d = %i \n", num1, num2, p);
    }

    if( strcmp( name, "addition" ) == 0 )
    {
      p = num1+num2;
      printf("%d + %d = %i \n", num1, num2, p);
    }

    if( strcmp( name, "multiplication" ) == 0 )
    {
      p = num1*num2;
      printf("%d x %d = %i \n", num1, num2, p);
    }

    if( strcmp( name, "division" ) == 0 )
    {
      if(num2==0)
         printf("undefiend\n");
      else
      {
        p = num1/num2;
        printf("%d / %d = %i \n", num1, num2, p);
      }
    }
  }
  char ch=getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling fgets, followed by fscanf, shouldn't you be calling fscanf by itself OR fgets followed by sscanf on the string fgets reads?

Comment: fgets (namecopy,21,file)!=NULL;-----

What you are doing with the values read in namecopy field???

Comment: strcpy(namecopy, name); This line seems pointless too, you are copying uninitialised name into namecopy, then overwriting it with the fgets.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
fscanf(file, "%[^,]%*c %i%*c %i%*c", &name, &num1, &num2);
```

should be

```
sscanf(namecopy, "%[^,]%*c %i%*c %i%*c", &name, &num1, &num2);
```

Comment: Thank you!, can you tell me why? so I can understand the mechanics of it?

Comment: fgets reads a line from the file.  fscanf immediately reads another line, without letting the program format the input from line 1.  Another probelm is that mixing fscanf and fgets to read the same file leads to file pointers that are not where you want them.  Stick with fgets for now.